# JavaScript to highlight active page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to utilize JavaScript to highlight the current page. I have a main menu and a sub menu on the page. I want the highlighted main menu to look different from the sub menu. Here is the JavaScript I came up with the apply a css class to the current page. How do I get the JavaScript to differentiate the two different classes?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass('main_current');
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').each(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
                $(this).addClass('sub_current');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your HTML?

Comment: I have seen it done like this before but I would advise against it for a couple of reasons. The best approach is to set the current page in the backend and not use JavaScript for this at all. If you are going to stick with this approach, you should consider using a string match instead and you should consider upper/lower case as `WWW.GOOGLE.COM` and `www.google.com` are not the same when using `==`. Also, `www.google.com` and `www.google.com/` will go to the same place but one will be `true`, the other will be `false` using your current function.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the page/code structure you're going for. I usually don't check `window.location`, but instead set `rel` attribute on the page body. On homepage body will have `rel="home"`, on some other page `rel='other-page` and so forth.

This way you can check for body's `rel` attribute and change menu/submenu's status based on that.

```
(function(){
   var currentLocation = $('body').attr('rel');

   switch(currentLocation){
       case 'home':
           //add class to the home link
           break;

       case 'other-page':
           //add class to the other link
           break;
   }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify better the selector when you iterate over the submenu and override some properties with 'sub_current'. EG:

If you have

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="thisPage.com">ThisMenu</a>
      <ul id="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="thisPage.com">ThisSubMenu</a></li> 
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

you could specify with `$('#sub-menu a')`.

I hope it helps.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The method below will do the same thing

```
$(function() {
 var url = document.location.href;
    if (url.indexOf("about") > -1) {
    $('#nav-bar ul li:contains("About")').addClass('sub_current');
}
 else if (url.indexOf("index") > -1) {
   $('#nav-bar ul li:contains("Home")').addClass('main_current');
}

else {
       // do something else
    }
});
```

**Note:** :contains selctor is case sensitive.